# Foursquare API - Popular Venue by Location and Date

Tags: api, foursquare

Is there a way to use the Foursquare API to get the most popular venues for a specific date in history in a given location?  For example, In Chicago, IL, on 08/01/2012, what where the venues with the most checkins? I've reviewed the search and trending endpoints and they do not have any date parameters available.  The trending endpoint would be perfect if it also allowed for a data parameter, so I could query what was trending yesterday, two weeks ago, etc..

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to query the API for the most popular place over a historical period of time.